# Am I tracing this correctly?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

My Computer Science teacher assigned us different sorting algorithms to hand trace. I wanted to be sure my tracing was correct
selectionSort:

```
void selection sort
{
  for(int i = 0; i < ray.length-1;i++)
  {
    int min = i
    for(int j = i +1; j<ray.length;j++;)
    {
      if(ray[j] < ray[min])
        min = j;
    }
    if(min != i)
    {
      int temp = ray[min]
      ray[min] = ray[i]
      ray[i] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

original array =  `{4,2,6,3,5,1}`
order of Sorting:

```
1st pass - 2,4,6,3,5,1
2nd pass - 2,3,6,4,5,1
3rd pass - 2,3,4,6,5,1
4th pass - 2,3,4,5,6,1
5th pass - 2,3,4,5,1,6
6th pass - 2,3,4,1,5,6
7th pass - 2,3,1,4,5,6
8th pass - 2,1,3,4,5,6
9th pass - 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: Add a c or c++ tag (doesn't appear to be java) as appropriate so your question gets more exposure.

Comment: Where are you in the code when you are doing each of your passes?

Comment: You can run the program and print the array before each pass & verify it yourself.

Comment: @Thiruvalluvar that won't really help you understand why you got that output. It's better to try and figure it out by hand and then run the code to see if you were correct.

Comment: @twain249 I said "verify it" NOT "copy it"

Comment: @Thiruvalluvar sorry I missed read your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your traces don't appear to be correct

when you start you have the array

```
{4,2,6,3,5,1}
```

During the outer loop

```
min = i // i = 0 min = 0
```

During the inner loop you do this

```
if(ray[j] < ray[min]) //2 < 4 TRUE (j = 1 min = 0)
   min = j;
//loop increment j
if(ray[j] < ray[min]) //6 < 2 FALSE (j = 2 min = 1)
//loop increment j
if(ray[j] < ray[min]) //3 < 2 FALSE (j = 3 min = 1)
//loop increment j
if(ray[j] < ray[min]) //5 < 2 FALSE (j = 4 min = 1)
//loop increment j
if(ray[j] < ray[min]) // 1 < 2 TRUE (j = 5 min = 1)
   min = j;
//loop increment j (j = 6 end loop)

if(min != i) //min = 5 i = 0 TRUE
   temp = ray[min] //temp = 1
   ray[min] ray[i] //ray[5] = ray[0] ray[5] = 4
   ray[i] = temp //ray[0] = 1

//loop increment i to 1 continue through this
```

Array at this point

```
{1,2,6,3,5,4}
```

You should be able to continue this for the rest of the outer loop